# How to access dfm resource at runtime (Delphi 11, 12)

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, delphi-11-alexandria, dfm, delphi-12-athens

How can a DFM resource of a form in a Delphi project be accessed in code at runtime?

Background: I want to be able to parse a form's DFM at runtime to create HTML and other representations of it on demand. Of course, I could parse them before building the project and create an extra resource. But as they are compiled into the software and used at runtime I believe they should also be accessible somehow in code.

I currently use Delphi 11 and soon Delphi 12.

Comment: Yes, your DFM files are attached to the EXE as regular resources, as you can see in any resource editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Vlu.png

Comment: Note, that the DFM is stored as binary in the exe, while the DFM file is usually in text form.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have looked with a tool likes this upfront! hopefully I can parse the binary dfm also.

Comment: It seems to be easy to convert with System.ObjectResourceToText. Thanks once more for this very fast help. I would love to accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RTL has classes and functions in the `System.Classes` unit for processing DFMs. After all, any Forms (or DataModules or Frames) in your project have to parse their own DFMs at runtime. That functionality is publicly accessible, so you can also parse DFMs yourself, too.

To answer your specific question - you can use the `TResourceStream` class to access a DFM resource, using the `ClassName` of the Form/DataModule/Frame that the DFM belongs to.

For example, when a `TCustomForm-`/`TDataModule-`/`TCustomFrame`-derived class loads its DFM at runtime:

- its constructor calls `InitInheritedComponent()` ...
- which calls `InternalReadComponentRes()`, passing in the target's `ClassName` and `HInstance` of the EXE/Package which its class is implemented in (that can be found using `FindClassHInstance()` and `FindResourceHInstance()`) ...
- which creates a `TResourceStream` object using the specified `HInstance` and  `ClassName` and `RT_RCDATA` resource type, and then calls its `ReadComponent()` method ...
- which creates a `TReader` object using `Self` as its source stream, and then calls its `ReadRootComponent()` method to parse the stream data and populate the target's properties.

You can use the `TReader` class directly in your own code for your own parsing needs.  You don't have to read the DFM values into a target Form/DataModule/Frame object.